# How do I access post_meta key with php?

Tags: php, html

Finally I've managed to achieve what I wanted to do in previous complicated questions :) Sorry for not being clear :/

So now this simple question:
I have this div:

```
<div style="display: block;"> content <div>
```

I want to replace "display: block;" with a php statement that checks the post_meta key "buy_status".

If there is no such post_meta key, then "display: block";

If the post_meta key exists, and its value is 1, then "display: none";

So what would that php statement be??

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), it should be something like:

```
<?php if(!get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'buy_status', true)): ?>
    display: block;
<?php else: ?>
    display: none;
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks no_nick! I will check out the docs reference. I wasn't sure how to make the php work but you cleared that up. Your example is an excellent clarifier and teacher. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)